# biopython (python3) phylo, how does the distance function works?

Tags: biopython

Using the Phylo package in Python3, I am trying to compute distances between two terminal nodes (leaves) of a neighbour-joining tree. To do this, the package implements a distance function. However, the distance function gives me a different result from what is in my newick file (the difference is very light but quite important in my work). Here is my code:

```
#Libraries  

import os
from Bio import Phylo
from io import StringIO

# Tree
handleD = StringIO("((E:0.2,D:0.1,C:0.1,B:0.3)2:0.3,A:0.5)1;")
treeD = Phylo.read(handleD,"newick")

# Distance
treeD.distance("E","D")
```

**The distance returns 0.30000000000000004 and not 0.3 as describe in the newick format.**

I tried to look at the source code: http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Phylo.BaseTree.TreeMixin-class.html#distance
that leads to that function : http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Nexus.Trees-pysrc.html#Tree.sum_branchlength
but it doesn't explain why there is a difference in the values.

Have you got an explanation why the function returns 0.30000000000000004 instead of 0.3 as described in the newick format?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Indeed ! Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: And some python specific read on this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html